# Ruby on rails 4 - What would be the best way to allow one user to see the data of another user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions

I want to allow one user on my app to chose who can see his own data, I don't know if I'm really clear so here is an example :

User A creates data on a table and he can only see his own data and/or decide to share it with another user.

User B can only see the data from another user that allowed him to do so.

I was thinking of some random token generated when the user is created and then the user can decide to share this token with someone else and then display the data based on this token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your "business rules" here. For instance, in an application I developed read rights were based on "privacy levels". Privacy level `0` meant that only you can view the data whereas privacy level `1` denoted that anybody could view the data. All of my queries were tailored to that datapoint, and a model relation to the user denoted the "owner."

So in your scheme, you propose a system where each record has it's own permission token, much like the system used in Google docs. This is a totally valid way of sharing records in a system. You could also get much more complex by allowing users to add users to the record, which might be another optimal solution for your use case.

Anyway, those are just a few thoughts on the subject. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think the way were a user can add another user to his record would be the best.  The app would be used by children and I need to have a way to let the parents/family see the child data, so it would need to be user specific and not based on a boolean privacy level. Do you know if there is a good gem/tutorial/documentation for this type of auth?

Comment: This really comes down to how you query for your data. If a relation exists, then the user has view permissions. If a relation doesn't exist then the user doesn't see the record. You should be able to do this one with just ActiveRecord.